# Why doesn't my div or navbar stretch all the way to the right?

Tags: html, css

I want my div and navbar's width stretch all the way to the right 100% but for some reason, it stops right before it reaches it. I've added screen cap of what I see

[screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkpqx.jpg)

css

```
.section2{
        font-size: 2em;
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: .75;
}
```

HTML

```
<section class="section2">
<div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="font-size:.75em" >
        <div class="col-md-12" >

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="font-size:.75em">
        <div class="col-md-12">text

 </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br><br>
<div class="row" align="center">
    <div class="col-md-12">
    text
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="font-size:.75em">
        <div class="col-md-12">Text

 </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: yes............

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution body and html should be set to 0 margin and padding

```
html, body {



margin:0;

padding:0;



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the parent of your section2 isn't at 100% of your screen.